# on SQL Server 2005 user can see just his/her database not all

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

have a web hosting service that is using MS SQL Server 2005 Express Edition. I have enabled remote database access , but I want to set permission for users so that when they login to Management studio they just see their database not all databases that I have on server. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

deny the 'view any database' permission to the login.

```
DENY VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [userlogin]
```

To do this for all logins into the database server, then revoke the view any database permission from the public role

```
REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE FROM [public]
```

Comment: I tried this out on our dev server and people were not able to see databases they had access to, just dbs they OWN.

Comment: Looks like you'd have to grant view definition for each role on each db for non-dbos.

Comment: yes if you revoke view any database from [public] you will have to grant the permission to every login.  You can put it back with GRANT VIEW ANY DATABASE TO [public]

Comment: why do you need to grant view definition?

Comment: @Sam but 'view definition' doesn't let people see the database when connecting with SSMS after REVOKE VIEW ANY DATABASE FROM [public]